# Android - Using volley and not getting a response

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to use Volley to implement a login feature in my app. I'm connecting to localhost and executing a script to get the data from the database. Using logs, I see that the execution never enters into the `onResponse` part of the `Response.Listener` object.

Here is the code:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse()");
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        boolean email_found = jsonResponse.getBoolean("email_found");

                        if (success) {
                            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivity.OPTIONS_TAG);
                            if (fragment == null) {
                                fragment = new LoginFragment();
                            }
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, MainActivity.OPTIONS_TAG).commit();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfull login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (email_found){
                            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                        } else {
                            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
                            mEmailView.requestFocus();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };


            Log.d(TAG, "LoginRequest");
            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email,password, responseListener);
```

The `LoginRequest` class:

```
class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://localhost/myportal/login.php";
    private Map <String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest (String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;

    }
}
```

And the PHP Script:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "myportal");

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $response = array();
    $response["email_found"]=false;

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["email_found"]=true;
    }

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $lastname, $email, $password, $year);

    $response["success"] = false;

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["lastname"] = $lastname;
        $response["email"] = $email;
        $response["password"] = $password;
        $response["year"] = $year;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Logcat output:

```
05-24 21:29:05.812 2114-2496/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [133] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for https://android.googleapis.com/nova/herrevad/network_quality_info
05-24 21:29:05.812 2114-17798/com.google.android.gms W/RmtRprtRfrshSvc: [19078] RemoteReportsRefreshService.a: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.ServerError
                                                                        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.ServerError
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.doGet(SourceFile:117)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.get(SourceFile:88)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.herrevad.services.RemoteReportsRefreshService.a(SourceFile:134)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.herrevad.services.RemoteReportsRefreshService.a(SourceFile:89)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.au.run(SourceFile:140)
                                                                         Caused by: com.android.volley.ServerError
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(SourceFile:163)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.server.v.performRequest(SourceFile:64)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(SourceFile:112)
05-24 21:29:05.946 1532-2199/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
05-24 21:29:05.947 2114-17806/com.google.android.gms E/ProtoReq: [19079] a.a: want to send authenticated request, but no Google account on device
05-24 21:29:18.207 2114-18125/com.google.android.gms W/BaseAppContext: Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
```

Comment: use "10.0.0.2" or open cmd type "ipconfig " copy the IP from there and replace localhost part from url with it

Comment: @mohammadawad Just tried that but same things happens. The log message doesn't print .

Comment: what does it show in logcat ? is there any excpetion show up ?

Comment: @mohammadawad check my OP, added the logcat.

Comment: You are not able to connect with the localhost...that;s why you are getting server error

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to change the IP to the appropriate one and add my RequestQueue, which I had forgot.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
queue.add(loginRequest);
```